# Spinner onItemSelected returning only the last item of the array

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm trying to implement multiple spinners in the app, in which the data is populated after a volley call. It should work in such way that; based on the selection of the first spinner value `"id"`, the second spinner should populate its value from another api call taking the selected `"id"` as parameter. 
I'm able to show the `"name"`(s) in the spinner now. But not sure how to get the `id` of the selected item for the second api call. Right now when I select any item in the first spinner, it only returns the `id` of the last item in the array.

**Json Array Response:**

```
[
  {
     "id":1,
     "name":"Roger Federer",
     "country":"Switzerland",
     "city":"Basel"

  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "name":"Rafael Nadal",
     "country":"Spain",
     "city":"Madrid"
  },
  {
     "id":3,
     "name":"Novak Djokovic",
     "country":"Serbia",
     "city":"Monaco"
  },
  {
     "id":4,
     "name":"Andy Murray",
     "country":"United Kingdom",
     "city":"London"
  },
  {
     "id":5,
     "name":"Maria Sharapova",
     "country":"Russia",
     "city":"Moscow"
  },
  {
     "id":8,
     "name":"Ana Ivanovic",
     "country":"Serbia",
     "city":"Belgrade"
  }
]
```

**FirstLevel** (model)

```
public class FirstLevel {


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

private String title;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

private int id;
}
```

**Java code**

```
private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

private ArrayList<FirstLevel> FirstLevelDataAdapterClassList;

private int selectedFirstLevel;
...
public void FIRST_LEVEL_WEB_CALL(final ViewHolder viewHolder) {

    //showSimpleProgressDialog(context, "Loading...", "Fetching Json", false);
    JsonArrayRequest jsArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, HTTP_SERVER_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    FIRST_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response,viewHolder);
                    Log.i("FL", "FL");
                    //removeSimpleProgressDialog();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }) {

    };

    requestQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue2.add(jsArrRequest);

}
public void FIRST_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array, final ViewHolder viewHolder) {

    FirstLevelDataAdapterClassList = new ArrayList<>();

    FirstLevel GetFirstLvDataModel = new FirstLevel();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            GetFirstLvDataModel.setId(json.getString("id"));
            GetFirstLvDataModel.setName(json.getString("name"));
            FirstLevelDataAdapterClassList.add(GetFirstLvDataModel);
            names.add(FirstLevelDataAdapterClassList.get(i).getTitle().toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, simple_spinner_item, names);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
        viewHolder.spinFirst.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        viewHolder.spinFirst.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


         selectedFirstLevel=FirstLevelDataAdapterClassList.get(position).getId();

                Log.i("FLFL",selectedFirstLevel);
                SECOND_LEVEL_WEB_CALL(viewHolder,selectedFirstLevel);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: get the value from your names list based on the position of the selected item

Comment: Could you show me how to do it my code?

Comment: @Puneet can you see my updated question? Now only I'm able to get the id of the last item despite of the selection

Comment: can you past whole source code file ?

Comment: @VishalG.Gohel Added more code.. didn't add full since its huge.. kindly let me know how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FirstLevel GetFirstLvDataModel = new FirstLevel();
```

should be declare in forloop and adapter is outside of the loop.

try this method ->

```
public void FIRST_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array, final ViewHolder viewHolder) {

    FirstLevelDataAdapterClassList = new ArrayList<>();


    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            FirstLevel GetFirstLvDataModel = new FirstLevel(); // Define class object here
            GetFirstLvDataModel.setId(json.getString("id"));
            GetFirstLvDataModel.setName(json.getString("name"));
            FirstLevelDataAdapterClassList.add(GetFirstLvDataModel);
            names.add(FirstLevelDataAdapterClassList.get(i).getTitle().toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // Close for loop here
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, simple_spinner_item, names);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
    viewHolder.spinFirst.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    viewHolder.spinFirst.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            selectedFirstLevel=FirstLevelDataAdapterClassList.get(position).getId();

            Log.i("FLFL",selectedFirstLevel);
            SECOND_LEVEL_WEB_CALL(viewHolder,selectedFirstLevel);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your this line

```
selectedFirstLevel= //How to get the 'id' of the selected item here?
```

will be

```
selectedFirstLevel = FirstLevelDataAdapterClassList.get(position).getId();
```

Try this out. Thanks

Comment: Its `.getId();` not `.getId;`

Comment: it was typo, but in IDE it was '.getId()' , still got the error

Comment: Can you see the updated question and let me know why its only returning the id of the last item in the array

Comment: I think you do not need to write first two lines : `String selected =parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
             int pos = names.indexOf(selected);` and use `position` instead of `pos`

Comment: I tried that and it still returns `id` of  the last item of the array